# Device boots old version after update TWRP

Tags: recovery-mode, twrp, fastboot

Out of the blue, my tablet (Samsung Galaxy Note 10.1 wifi) made a reboot and got stuck in the loading screen. So I tried to install a new ROM (sideload), but noticed that I can't because then the installer says

```
installing zip file '/sideload/package.zip' error executing updater
```

Then I thought, well maybe I should update TWRP to a newer version. So I did, at least, I thought I did. This is the most annoying android hell I've ever been in. I updated TRWP from 2.8.6 to 3.2.3, but when I reboot directly into recovery mode, which I did manually because I unchecked reboot option in Odin, I found out that the stupid Device is still loading 2.8.6. Next, I tried the same update from within TRWP itself. The flash succeeded, Reboot into recovery again and.. nope. Still 2.8.6. What the hell?

So then I tried pushing a simple test file to the filesystem /sdcard and /tmp and a custom /dl directory using adb commands. Then I reboot, aaand gone are the files. It seems my whole device is stuck in a permanent state. I can't change anything.

I gave up now. I'm working on this hell for 3 days and there is absolutely no positive movement at all. Why does Odin say flash passed, TRWP flash succeeded  and when I reboot, I still get the old crap? How can I flash my device from here on? It seems I'm stuck with it now forever. It doesn't update.

Other things I noticed:

- When I load into TWRP I can use ADB commands from my Win 10 PC.
- When I load into Fastboot mode, I can **not** use Fastboot commands. The device is not seen when using `fastboot devices` command.
- I can not see any file inside /data seems to be empty folder?
- When reloading TWRP theme, /data/media/0.. seems to be inexistent.
- I got the Samsung Android USB drivers installed on my windows 10 pc. Device manager shows ADB device when I boot into recovery. But no Fastboot device when I boot into fastboot.

What is going on here? How can I fix this?